# Inverse of certain symmetric 2x2 block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices

Let $M$ be a complex $2n\times 2n$-matrix of the form
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\ -B &A\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $A$ is a symmetric $n\times n$-matrix and $B$ a skew-symmetric $n\times n$-matrix. In particular, $M$ is symmetric.

I would like to know the precise conditions on $A$ and $B$ such that $M$ is invertible, and then a formula for $M^{-1}$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ which is ***as easy as possible***. In particular, the formula should take into account that A and B are symmetric and skew-symmetric, respectively.

The literature on general block matrix inversion formulas is so  overwhelming that I can find only results which are way too general for my purpose (e.g. the inversion formulas given in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix)).

Thank you very much in advance for any helpful comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, I found out a satisfying answer myself, at least in the case where $A$ and $B$ are real, which suffice for my purposes. In the book *Matrix Theory* by Fuzhen Zhang (2nd edition, p. 48), it says that if $A$ and $B$ are real $n\times n$-matrices, then
$$
det\begin{pmatrix}A & -B\\ B & A \end{pmatrix}=|det(A+iB)|^2,
$$
which implies that the matrix on the left hand side is invertible iff $A+iB$ is, and the book also says that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}A & -B\\ B & A \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}E & -F\\ F & E \end{pmatrix}\qquad \text{if }(A+iB)^{-1}=E+iF.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A$ and the Schur complement $S = A + BA^{-1}B$ are invertible. Then the inverse of $M$ is given by

$$
M^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A^{-1}(I - S^{-1}BA^{-1}) & -A^{-1}BS^{-1}\\
S^{-1}BA^{-1} & S^{-1}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is just the usual block inversion formula.

Comment: I know that formula, but it does not suffice for my purposes: M might be invertible even when A or the Schur complement are not invertible. This is the case also for the analogous standard formula that expresses the inverse of M in terms of the Schur complement of B. However, I guess that M can be invertible even if neither A nor B are invertible. I had hoped that in the given special situation, i.e. A symmetric and B skew-symmetric, there is a simple formula of the sort "M is invertible iff XXX holds, and then the inverse is given by YYY".

Comment: Do you have a source for the relation $det(M)=det(A^2+B^2)$? I don't see directly why it holds if $A$ and $B$ do not commute. The inverse of $M$ appears in some formulas of my research, and I am just curious whether it can be expressed more explicitly.

Comment: You are correct, I forgot that $A$ and $B$ need to commute.